# How do I toggle a command in 1 discord server instead of across all discord servers the bot is in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am programming a discord bot that has a few commands, dealt with by a command handler I made. I will include code below. My issue is that if I enable the command, it toggles across every server the bot is in. So how do I implement a `message.guild.id` system that only toggles a command in the server the command was typed in?
**Christian.js - the external file being read from the handler**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

exports.run = (bot, message, args, christian) => {
  if (args[0] === 'off') christian = false
  else if (args[0] === 'on') christian = true
  message.channel.send(`Christian Mode ${christian[message.guild.id] ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}`)
  return christian[message.guild.id]
}

exports.help = {
  name: 'christian'
}
```

- i have tried to add guilds, but have failed miserably
  **(part of) index.js - main file**

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
  const {author, channel, content} = msg

  if (author.bot) return

  try {
    if (content.startsWith(prefix)) {
      const args = content.toLowerCase().substring(prefix.length).split(/\s+/g)
      const command = args.shift()

      readdir(join(__dirname, 'commands')).then(files => {
        files.map(file => require(join(__dirname, 'commands', file))).forEach(cmd => {
          if (command === cmd.help.name) {
            const resultchristian = cmd.run(bot, msg, args, christian)
            if (typeof resultchristian !== 'undefined') christian = resultchristian
          }
        })
      })
      return
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Command loading error has cccured')
  }

  if (christian[msg.guild.id]) {
    const messages = {
      fdck: 'frick',
      biadtch: 'nasty person',
      nadr: 'nibba',
      ndga: 'smelly person',
      padsy: 'child',
      pude: 'child',
      casdnt: 'threat to society',
      bdrd: 'threat to society',
      dsk: 'widly'
    }
    try {
      const message = messages[content.toLowerCase()]
      if (message) msg.delete() & channel.send(message).then((m) => m.delete(10000));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('An error has occurred - make sure the bot has delete message permissions')
    }
  }
})
```

for some reason I cannot get my code to work with guilds.

Thank you in advance,

Joe (proto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it like this:

```
 if (args[0] === 'off') christian[message.guild.id] = false
 else if (args[0] === 'on') christian[message.guild.id] = true
```

and

```
return christian
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean I would like the bot to only toggle the command in the server the command was typed in - not every server the bot is in. - I do not mind about specific servers.

Comment: @Proto Then you have to create a file, where you will store servers, where it's enabled.
I think you're messing variable types, you're setting christian to boolean then try to resolve it as an object

Comment: Oh dear, this will be more complicated than I thought. I will need to store the guild ids of the servers in a file where I can dictate whether Christian is on or off - this may take a hot second.

Comment: When I do that, it posts Christian Mode Inactive no matter what I type. Its such a strange error in so little code - I need to work out whether Christian[message.guild.id] is returning true or false depending on the argument :/

Comment: Add me at my discord Tomas Gaming#7156